# Twitter UITableViewCell Link Detection for iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to reproduce the effect in Twitter for iOS where if you click on the text of tweet but **NOT** on the link (assuming this tweet has a link) it segues to a Tweet view controller but if you click on the actual link then it opens the link in a browser.

I understand how to detect and open links with UITextViews using the **shouldInteractWithURL** delegate method, but I'm confused as to how to implement a touch on the rest of the UITextView that doesn't open the link but performs another action, in this case opening a Tweet view controller.

I've tried hooking a tap gesture to the UITextView but I can't seem separate the tap detected via gesture from the shouldInteractWithURL call and so when I click on a link both actions occur, instead of just opening the link.

Btw all this is happening inside a UITableViewCell.

Any help in how to proceed would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to make sure that if there is an http you want it to open up some type of webview whereas other parts of the `UITextView` being clicked, segues somewhere else.

There are a few ways to go about this. Rather than using a `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you can disregard the delegate and detect the exact `CGPoint` that was clicked:

```
let buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: view)
let indexPath = view.indexPathForItemAtPoint(buttonPosition)
```

and for the detection of hyperlinks, perhaps you can use something like regex to make/detect links or use something like [Active Label](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) if you're using Swift.

Comment: Thanks! ActiveLabel did the trick for me. I was under the impression UITextViews were the only way to go for link detection but this worked great

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to get the right resource and come up with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the UITableViewCell segue to open the new View controller when it is tapped

Comment: Hmm I was unable to detect links in a UITextView unless I set it to selectable, and once it's selectable it doesn't pass touches along to the UITableViewCell hence the need for a tapGestureRecognizer...etc